# Генерация golang кода из proto файла

Tags: golang, модули, grpc

При попытке генерации (**protoc -I=proto --go_out=. proto/*.proto**) выдает ошибку:

"protoc-gen-go" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
--go_out: protoc-gen-go: Plugin failed with status code 1.

**protoc** установлен, в PATH добавлен путь, команда **go get github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go** выполнена. В чем может быть проблема.

Comment: В том что нужно ещё [добавить в PATH](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/) bin папку, куда копируются бинарные файлы от пакетов.

Comment: это wondows?  если просто запустить `protoc --help ` то что выводит?

Comment: protoc --help выводит список команд для protoc. Сделал все тоже самое на wsl с ubuntu - все работает. В windows, как и в ubuntu добавлял все переменные среды, какие требовались, так что думаю ошибка все же не в этом.

Comment: @KinitaL на windows откройте терминал. выполните `echo %PATH%` там есть путь, где лежит protoc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`protoc` - это компиляторный фронтэнд, который парсит `.proto` файлы. Для генерации файлов на языке `Go` ему нужен кодогенератор `protoc-gen-go`.

Кодогенератор устанавливается командой

```
go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@latest
```

в директорию `$GOPATH/bin`. Если вы хотите установить его в какую-то другую директорию, задайте её в переменной окружения `$GOBIN`.

Соответственно, для того, чтобы `protoc` работал, необходимо, чтобы директория `$GOPATH/bin` была в составе переменной окружения `PATH`.